# Filtering a data frame by date in R

Tags: r, date, subset

In R I have imported data from a tab-separated text file into a data.frame.
The table looks like this:

```
latitude longitude date         temperature
-------- --------- ------       -----------
50.45989 15.363366 "2014-01-29" -14.4
50.00911 15.323255 "2014-01-30" -10.2
50.88900 15.440032 "2014-01-29" -14.4
```

When I write the command:

```
str(mydata)
```

I get the following result:

```
'data.frame':   211931 obs. of  10 variables:
$ latitude      : num  50.8 50.8 50.8 50.8 50.8 ...
$ longitude: num  15.6 15.6 15.6 15.6 15.6 ...
$ date : Factor w/ 581 levels "2012-07-01","2012-07-02",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
$ temperature  : num  -14.4.6 -15.5 -10.1 -9.2 NA ...
```

I want to create a subset of the data frame that only contains rows with date equal to 29th January 2014. How do I do this in R?

I tried the commands:

```
datefilter = as.Date("2014-01-29")
selection = mydata[mydata[date]==datefilter]
```

But R complains about: Cannot convert type "factor" to "date".

Comment: you should convert `$ date` to a date format before trying your filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the output of `str()` is telling you, your date column has been read into R as a factor, rather than a Date column. Indeed, the error message you get explicitly says "Cannot convert type "factor" to "date"". Of course, it's not that it isn't possible, R just can do that automatically, since dates could be in any number of different formats.

So you simply need to convert your date column to an actual date format. You'll want to do:

```
mydata$date <- as.Date(mydata$date)
```

Another route to go would be to handle the conversion at the point of data import. This could be done via the `colClasses` argument to `read.table`, which in your case it looks like you'd want to use something like:

```
read.table(...,colClasses = c("numeric","numeric","Date","numeric"))
```

Comment: `as.Date(dat$date)` worked for me. Do you have an example when it will coerce to integer then apply `as.Date`?

Comment: @rawr Nope. I just forgot that `as.Date.factor` calls `as.character` already for you.

Comment: I tried using the colClasses argument suggestion: `read.table(...,colClasses = c("numeric","numeric","Date","numeric"))` Now, when I do `str(mydata)` R shows that my 'date' column is type 'Date' and I don't get the 'cannot convert factor to date' error.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code should work:

```
library(dplyr)
desired.subset <- data.frame %>% filter(date == '2014-01-14')
```